# filtering webservice request with viewXml

Tags: javascript, web-services, filter, ajax, sharepoint-on-prem

**Situation**

I have a Ajax query that gets all items from my list it gets all items (1000 ish) and the query alone takes about 1.3 seconds of the total load time of 1.5 seconds.

**Problem**

I know this will scale up in time on the live site.(more users and items)
I have to use the following code because it gets me the taxonomy values.

So basicly my question is: can i filter the following code by multiple id's and if so how?

Thanks in advance!

Code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url +"/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('"+ listname+"')/GetItems(query=@v1)?@v1={'ViewXml':'<View><Query></Query></View>'}",
    type: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    },
    success: function (data) {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my Problem:

Useing `type` instead of `Type` which gave weird errors which made me believe that filtering useing this method of caml wasn't possible, because when it didn't gave errors it just ignored the filters.

There should really be better error message descriptions (Especially since I get german one's)

```
var caml = '<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="ID"/><Value Type="Counter">160</Value></Eq></Where></Query>';

$.ajax({
        url: url +"/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('"+ listname+"')/GetItems(query=@v1)?@v1={'ViewXml':'<View>"+ caml +"</View>'}",
        type: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(jqXHR);
        }
    });
```

Hope this helps someone else as wel!